# Xamarin.Forms - WebKit WebView (SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview) vertical scroll issue

Tags: android, webview, xamarin.forms

I'm having a problem with SKLn-Rad HybridWebView. When a try to scroll down the view goes up and vice versa. I think is a problem with WebView in general because before using this hybrid webview I have the same issue.

XAML Code:

```
<StackLayout
        Padding="3"
        BackgroundColor="#e2cedf"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <webview:FormsWebView
                x:Name="WebContent"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                ContentType="Internet"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                OnContentLoaded="OnNavigated"
                OnNavigationCompleted="OnNavigated"
                OnNavigationStarted="OnNavigating"
                Source="https://purpuraylimon.com/"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

        </Grid>

    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I use your code, but I don't find any issue when I scroll down the view, can you description what issue have you encountered here?

Comment: When I'm scrolling down it freezes or scrolls up and never can reach the end of the main page. When I was starting the project I use the Xamarin.Forms default WebView and have the same issue but I solved using the SKLn-Rad HybridWebView and adding some settings in the MainActivity to the Android.Webkit.WebView.Settings, but in some point this week it stops working and the issue came back.